# ¿Cómo reparar: Error running in app: No JDK specified android studio?

Tags: android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] Creo que por error quité una dependencia o librería y ya no me deja correr la app.

```
08:48:24 PM Error Loading Project: Cannot load 7 facets Details...
08:51:22 PM [![Error running com.mark.exportadora in app: No JDK specified][1]][1]
```

Comment: Mark, revisa si tienes el path correcto de tu JDK y que en realidad este instalado.

Answer (score 1):

Asegura tener instalado el JDK y define el path correcto, puedes acceder mediante `Open Module Settings`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En windows regularmente el path es algo similar a :

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk.....\
```

Comment: si ya instale y desistale

Comment: Define el path correcto, la imagen que agregue es de una Mac, revisa en tu pc  cual es el correcto path, en Windows es algo similar a: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk.....\